# How to store sharedPreferences on Google Drive correctly?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

Log in and receive permission from Google already has.
Already I know how to create, delete, empty files, but I can not write data to a file.
Tell me how to send sharedPreferences file to Google Drive, and how to get it back.
Can you just describe the steps I could find - I would be very grateful!

Something like that:

- Open the file *(File f = getActivity () getDatabasePath (
  "prefname");.)*
- Get mime *(f.getMime)*
- Get in bytes *(f.toByte)*
- Writing to Drive *(DriveFile DF = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder (apiClient)
                               .createFile (apiKlient, metadata, bytes)*

PS: I'm so tired of all the search ...

Comment: I do not recall there being an official API for getting at the file where `SharedPreferences` are stored. I suggest that you store your data in some other container (e.g., a JSON file) that you can manage directly.

Comment: `File f = getActivity () getDatabasePath ( "prefname")`. Wrong path. Better try `String path = getFilesDir().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/shared_prefs/<packagename>_preferences.xml"`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. But I'm interested in downloading Google Drive on any file.
I want to learn how to organize it properly.